# Match column names with another dataframe and split into separate dataframes

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe (`df`) which looks like this:

```
tex21.222   chic56.345  wa34.907
0.5         0.6         1.12
0.8         1.2         0.9
```

I want to partition this dataframe into separate dataframes, based on another dataframe called `keys`, which looks like this:

```
site_name   sample_name
tex_1       tex21.222
tex_1       tex23.234
chic_1      chic56.345 
wa_1        wa34.907
wa_2        wa24.277
```

For every column of `df`, I want to (1) match the column name with `sample_name` in `keys` to get `site_name`, (2) move all columns that have the same `site_name` from `df` into separate dataframes.

So, in the end, I want to have separate dataframes with all columns that fall within `tex_1`, all columns that fall within `chic_1` etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
data <- df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  left_join(keys,by = c('name'='sample_name'))
#Split
List <- split(data,data$site_name)
List <- lapply(List,function(x) {x$site_name<-NULL;x})
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Outputs:

```
List
$chic_1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name       value
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 chic56.345   0.6
2 chic56.345   1.2

$tex_1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name      value
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 tex21.222   0.5
2 tex21.222   0.8

$wa_1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name     value
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 wa34.907  1.12
2 wa34.907  0.9
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you :)

Comment: @fifigoblin Always a pleasure helping you!

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `merge` + `stack` + `split`

```
u <- merge(stack(df1), df2, by.x = "ind", by.y = "sample_name")
split(u[c("ind", "values")], u$site_name)
```

gives

```
$chic_1
         ind values
1 chic56.345    0.6
2 chic56.345    1.2

$tex_1
        ind values
3 tex21.222    0.5
4 tex21.222    0.8

$wa_1
       ind values
5 wa34.907   1.12
6 wa34.907   0.90
```